# Is it allowed to extend the std::numbers namespace with new definitions?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, c++20

I have several mathematical numeric constants defined in a large codebase. Several of which (but not all) are now duplicated in the new C++20 `<numbers>` header. I'd like to have them all in one place; is it allowed to extend the `std::numbers` header to include the ones not already defined?

Comment: why not import (using) the standard ones into your own mynumbers namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it allowed to extend the std::numbers header to include the ones not already defined?

No, you may not add definitions to `std` namespace nor its subnamespaces (except for class template specialisations in cases where that isn't explicitly disallowed).

You can instead have them all in one place in your own namespace with `using` declartions:

```
namespace Casey
{
    inline constexpr double missing_number = 123;

    using std::numbers::e;
    // ...
}
```

Instead of `using` each number individually, you could use `using namespace std::numbers`, but that has the caveat that future standard versions may add numbers whose names may potentially conflict with yours, breaking future compatibility of your header.

Comment: `...whose names may potentially conflict with yours...`; this already happened when I used `using namespace std::numbers`. I had a variable named `e` in a local scope and there was a conflict. Time to add `using` declarations for all the values!